# MySQL IF ELSEIF in select query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to select different prices of a product based on the quantity that user chooses.
This is the query I'm working on (it has a syntax error):

```
 select id, 
    (SELECT 
    IF(qty_1<='23',price,1)
    ELSEIF(('23'>qty_1 && qty_2<='23'),price_2,1)
    ELSEIF(('23'>qty_2 && qty_3<='23'),price_3,1)
    ELSEIF('23'>qty_3,price_4,1)
    END IF) as total 
 from product;
```

Comment: you should use CASE

Answer (score 280, accepted):

You have what you have used in stored procedures [like this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html) for reference, but they are not intended to be used as you have now. You can use `IF` as shown by `duskwuff`. But a `Case` statement is better for eyes. Like this:

```
select id, 
    (
    CASE 
        WHEN qty_1 <= '23' THEN price
        WHEN '23' > qty_1 && qty_2 <= '23' THEN price_2
        WHEN '23' > qty_2 && qty_3 <= '23' THEN price_3
        WHEN '23' > qty_3 THEN price_4
        ELSE 1
    END) AS total
 from product;
```

This looks cleaner. I suppose you do not require the inner `SELECT` anyway..

Comment: Yes indeed, it looks better, I will choose this option but its good to have both approaches for future references.. Thanks nawfal

Answer (score 31):

`IF()` in MySQL is a ternary function, not a control structure -- if the condition in the first argument is true, it returns the second argument; otherwise, it returns the third argument. There is no corresponding `ELSEIF()` function or `END IF` keyword.

The closest equivalent to what you've got would be something like:

```
IF(qty_1<='23', price,
  IF('23'>qty_1 && qty_2<='23', price_2,
    IF('23'>qty_2 && qty_3<='23', price_3,
      IF('23'>qty_3, price_4, 1)
    )
  )
)
```

The conditions don't all make sense to me (it looks as though some of them may be inadvertently reversed?), but without knowing what exactly you're trying to accomplish, it's hard for me to fix that.

Comment: i figure that out a min ago... 

select productoid, precio, precio_2, precio_3, IF(cant_1>23,precio, IF (23>cant_1 && cant_2>23,precio_2,IF (23>cant_2 && cant_3>23,precio_3,IF (23>cant_4,precio_4,1)))) as total from producto

the thing is that im not able to create a stand-alone price table because of my bosses request that would be much easier to make a join and get the price based on the quantity...

Comment: a closer thing would be using `case when (condition) then {computed value} when then else end`

Answer (score 11):

I found a bug in MySQL 5.1.72 when using the nested if() functions .... the value of column variables (e.g. qty_1) is blank inside the second if(), rendering it useless. Use the following construct instead:

```
case 
  when qty_1<='23' then price
  when '23'>qty_1 && qty_2<='23' then price_2
  when '23'>qty_2 && qty_3<='23' then price_3
  when '23'>qty_3 then price_4
  else 1
end
```

Answer (score 4):

For your question :

```
SELECT id, 
   IF(qty_1 <= '23', price,
   IF(('23' > qty_1 && qty_2 <= '23'), price_2,
   IF(('23' > qty_2 && qty_3 <= '23'), price_3,
   IF(('23' > qty_2 && qty_3<='23'), price_3,
   IF('23' > qty_3, price_4, 1))))) as total 
FROM product;
```

You can use the `if - else` control structure or the `IF` function in MySQL.

Reference:
http://easysolutionweb.com/sql-pl-sql/how-to-use-if-and-else-in-mysql/

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Answer (score 2):

As per Nawfal's answer, IF statements need to be in a procedure. I found this post that shows a brilliant example of using your script in a procedure while still developing and testing. Basically, you create, call then drop the procedure:

https://gist.github.com/jeremyjarrell/6083251