# How to do select if else statement in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample Data:

```
[{url: bing.com},
{url: bing.com/search?q=test}, 
{url: bing.com/efesdf+sdsdksd}]
```

I would like to return all url string before '?' or '+', which means it will return bing.com/search for 2nd url and bing.com/efesdf for 3rd, removing anything after '?' or '+'

Thus I tried the code below

```
SELECT substring(url,1,instr(pattern,'?')-1) FROM testTable;
```

However doing this url without '?' will be shown as "", is it possible to do a if statement like

```
if (url.includes('?')){
SELECT substring(url,1,instr(url,'?')-1)
}
else if (url.includes('+')){
SELECT substring(url,1,instr(url,'+')-1)}
}  
else{
SELECT URL
}
FROM testTable;
```

and what if I would like to select * and alter only url?

Please assist,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need this;)

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('?', url) THEN LEFT(url, LOCATE('?', url) - 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('+', url) THEN LEFT(url, LOCATE('+', url) -1)
    ELSE url END AS editedUrl
FROM testTable;
```

Check [SQLFiddle DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6b2d/2).

Comment: Thanks a lot it had solved, anyway what if I want to select* at the same time edit the url?
maybe, 
SELECT *
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('?', url) THEN LEFT(url, LOCATE('?', url) - 1)
    WHEN LOCATE('+', url) THEN LEFT(url, LOCATE('+', url) -1)
    ELSE url END AS url
FROM testTable;

Comment: Thanks, a lot. appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You need this one?? [Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887616/mysql-if-elseif-in-select-query)

```
select id, 
        (
        CASE 
            WHEN qty_1 <= '23' THEN price
            WHEN '23' > qty_1 && qty_2 <= '23' THEN price_2
            WHEN '23' > qty_2 && qty_3 <= '23' THEN price_3
            WHEN '23' > qty_3 THEN price_4
            ELSE 1
        END) AS total
     from product;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN LOCATE('?', url ) > 0 
               THEN SUBSTRING( url, 0, LOCATE('?', url ) -1 )
            WHEN LOCATE('+', url ) > 0
                THEN SUBSTRING( url, 0, LOCATE('?', url ) -1 )
               ELSE url 
       END as url
FROM testTable;
```