# How do edit this mySQL query based on value of column without using PHP?

Tags: mysql

I want to edit my existing mySQL query based on whether the column `show_only_on` has a value or not.

If it has a value, then the correct query is the below

```
Select *
FROM alerts_data
WHERE id = 'abc' AND running_status='idle'
AND FIND_IN_SET("https://www.example.com/pricing", show_only_on)
```

And if it does not have a value, I just leave out the

`AND FIND_IN_SET("https://www.example.com/pricing", show_only_on)`

or make the `FIND_IN_SET` return true.

How can I do this using only this query and not any PHP ?

Comment: Might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887616/mysql-if-elseif-in-select-query

Comment: Otherwise see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to return all records where wither `show_only_on` is `NULL` *or* where `show_only_on` matches the `FIND_IN_SET` logic?

Sounds like this:

```
WHERE
    id = 'abc' AND
    running_status='idle' AND
    (
        FIND_IN_SET("https://www.example.com/pricing", show_only_on) OR
        show_only_on IS NULL
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

How about running it through an `OR/AND` statement?:

```
Select *
FROM alerts_data
WHERE id = 'abc' AND running_status='idle'
AND (
  show_only_on IS NULL /* Whatever check you do to ensure it's not set */
  OR FIND_IN_SET("https://www.example.com/pricing", show_only_on)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, one that I tend to use in parameterised queries:

```
WHERE id = 'abc'
AND running_status='idle'
AND COALESCE(show_only_on, "https://www.example.com/pricing") = "https://www.example.com/pricing"
```

Parameterised:

```
WHERE id = 'abc'
AND running_status = 'idle'
AND COALESCE(show_only_on, :url) = :url
```

Note this only works where `show_only_on` is `NULL` if and only if the value is considered empty/missing.